# Node JS - Cannot get stream data without pipe on promise-ftp

Tags: node.js, api, express, ftp

Hi guys I'm facing problem with my Node.js api with Express when I'm trying to get files from FTP and then send then over my API as base64.

I'm using -> promise-ftp (https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-ftp).

This is how endpoint looks like:

```js
getData = (req, res, next) => {
  const ftp = new PromiseFtp();
  let data = [];
  ftp.connect({host: 'xxxl',user: 'xxx',password: 'xxx'})
  .then(() => {
      return ftp.get('xxx.pdf');
    }).then((stream) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        stream.once('close', resolve);
        stream.once('error', reject);
        stream.pipe(fs.createReadStream('test.pdf'));
        
        stream
        .on('error', (err) => {
          return res.send({errorMessage: err});
        })
        .on('data', (chunk) => data.push(chunk))
        .on('end', () => {
          const buffer = Buffer.concat(data);
          label = buffer.toString('base64');
          
          return res.send(label);
         });
      });
    }).then(() => {
      return ftp.end();
    });
}
```

The problem is that I don't want to save this file localy  next to api files and when I remove line `stream.pipe(fs.createReadStream('test.pdf'));` it doesn't work.

I'm not sure what pipe is doing here.

May you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readable.pipe(writable)` is part of Node's Stream API, which transparently writes the data that is read from the readable into the writable stream, handling backpressure for you. Piping the data to the filesystem is unnecessary, and Express `Response` object implements the writable stream interface so you could just pipe the stream returned from the FTP promise directly to the `res` object.

```
getData = async (req, res) => {
  const ftp = new PromiseFtp();
  try {
    await ftp.connect({host: 'xxxl',user: 'xxx',password: 'xxx'});
    const stream = await ftp.get('xxx.pdf');
    res.type('pdf');
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      res.on('finish', resolve);
      stream.once('error', reject);
      stream.pipe(res);
    });
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    await ftp.end();
  }
}
```

If you don't have a Node version that supports `async`/`await`, here's a Promise-only version:

```
getData = (req, res) => {
  const ftp = new PromiseFtp();
  ftp
    .connect({host: 'xxxl',user: 'xxx',password: 'xxx'})
    .then(() => ftp.get('xxx.pdf'))
    .then(stream => {
      res.type('pdf');
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        res.on('finish', resolve);
        stream.once('error', reject);
        stream.pipe(res);
      });
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.error(e);
    })
    .finally(() => ftp.end());
}
```

Here you have a good use-case for using a Promise's `finally()`-method or a `try/catch/finally` block, which will ensure that `ftp.end()` is called even if an error occurs or not.

Note that I've deliberately left out sending the error back to clients as doing such things could possibly leak sensitive information. A better solution is to setup proper server-side logging with request context.

Comment: Hi Sven, thx for your response. Unfortunatelly I still not reach my goal. In the first proposal with async/await (i'm using it mostly in my api), all lokks fine but request is not ending and I'm still waiting for rensponse. Your second proposal is not working at all as ther is an error ```stream.pipe is not a function
```. May you please advice with 1 option what to do next. I thought that stream.pipe(res) will send response for this endpoint.. :(

Comment: Ok got it, I had to call ```res.end()```

Comment: Hi Sven may you please advice me how to check if stream has some data or something like this? Becasue ```HttpResponse``` on front-end has
```{
size: 0
type: "application/pdf"
}```

and I can download pdf but it is empty or even broken...

Comment: Hi @agims7, please see my updated answer. I had a bug that closed the ftp connection before it was done sending the data to the user. Note that the data is not base64 encoded, and instead sent as-is. You can load it into an arraybuffer or blob on the front-end. The FTP library you're using is ancient though, hasn't been updated in 3 years and the issue tracker is abandoned. You might want to use [basic-ftp](https://github.com/patrickjuchli/basic-ftp) instead if you keep having troubles.

Comment: you are genius :) all works fine. I will read more about streams as it looks like common case to use them. Much appreciated!

Comment: and by the way promise-ftp was last time updated 9 month ago so I thought it is fine. I cannot find similar method in basic-ftp like get from promise-ftp

Comment: @agims7 glad it worked out. I was refering to the [`node-ftp`](https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp) library that `promise-ftp` uses under the hood., which hasn't been updated in 3 years. Issues with that library will inherently seep through to the `promise-ftp` library.